# Unable to do rest call from dotnet code

Tags: c#, rest

I want to call  `http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=28078&format=json&num_of_days=1&key=<key>`

which will return me a `JSON` response in my .NET project.

**If I browse this URL in Chrome or in Fiddler or in PostMan I am able to get response in my test box, but through my code it is not working in the same test box.**

I am getting below error

```
@"System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 31.193.9.233:80
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Below is my dotnet code

```
 StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
        string response1 = "";

            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=28078&format=json&num_of_days=1&key=<key>");
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
                try
                {
                    WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
                    using (Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        if (webStream != null)
                        {
                            using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream))
                            {
                                 response1 = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    response1 = e.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response1 = ex.ToString(); 
            }

            st.Append("2");
            return response1;
```

From my development box also the dotnet code is able to get a response.
Only with test box it is not responding.

I think it is more related to machine setting but don't have much idea.

Please help.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy? I'd guess at that been the cause, there are lots of posts out there to help using .Net code behind a proxy server, it might be worth looking into that as your code works fine for me.

Comment: I've edited it out, but you should be careful not to include keys in code examples you place on the internet. You might want to contact Stack Overflow (via the contact link in the footer of this page) to remove it from the revision history as well.